# How can I apply for a Canadian visit visa as a refugee?

Tags: visas, canada, refugees

I am a refugee in South Africa with a refugee travel document. I would like to get a Canadian visit visa, what should I do?

Comment: Have you even looked at the [Canadian government website](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/apply-visitor-visa.html)?

Comment: An important consideration: [Until further notice, you can’t travel to Canada even if you have a valid visitor visa or electronic travel authorization (eTA).](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/coronavirus-covid19/visitors-foreign-workers-students.html)

Comment: @Samuel You could do some research eg google ‘how do I apply for a visa for Canada’

Comment: You just apply in the normal way, like everyone else. Is there something specific that you need help with?

Answer (score 2):

Online applications for Canadian visas start [here](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp).

Due to the coronavirus Canadian immigration is encouraging online applications. Be aware that you might be required to provide fingerprints and a photo in person.